# Understanding the following expression in an integration

Tags: integration, analysis, measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory

[image]

[image]

[image]

I cannot understand how the parts of this proof circled in red are obtained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. This is an inequality, which stems from the fact that the function $y\mapsto|x-y|^{-t}\mathbf 1_{|x-y|\gt1}$ is uniformly bounded by $1$ hence its integral is at most $\mu(\mathbb R^n)$.
2. This is an equality, which stems from the fact that $\mu$ is the restriction of $\mathcal H^s$ to $E\subseteq F$.